# Trouble sending and Interpreting form data sent via ajax through dynamically generated content

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Sorry for the overly complicated title, not sure how else to describe it.  So, here is what I have.

I am dynamically creating div's for each of a databases row content to act as a frame work for a gui.  That part works.  It generates a new div and properly displays it for each row of the db and propagates the requested data.  When you click on the generated gui it sends the data to another page for processing which is displayed in another div.  This all works.  What I am having trouble with is on the page which receives the send form data from the gui.  It either displays the entirety of the db's contents from the requested or if I add a where to the select statement the fetch request doesn't seem to fire off at all.

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","base","password","util");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo"
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
            $('#front').click(function (e){
              e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/pages/receivingpage.php',
                data: $(\"f2\").serialize(),
                success: function(d){
                  $(\"#content-disp\").html(d);
                }
              });
            });
          });//end document ready
        </script>

        <div id=\"covera\">

        <div id=\"holder\" class=\"holder\">

        <div id=\"disp\" class=\"disp\">

        <div class=\"click diagonal panel\">
          <div id=\"front\"  class=\"front\">
            <form id=\"" . $row['recipe'] ."\" name=\"f2\">
              <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"recipe\" value=\"" . $row['recipe'] ."\">
              <h2>" . $row['recipe'] ."<br></h2>
            </form> 
          </div>

          <div class=\"back\">
            <div class=\"pad\">
              <h2>" . $row['recipe'] ."</h2>
              <p>" . $row['id'] ."</p>
              <p>Number of Servings " . $row['servings'] ."</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div></div></div></div>";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the code for the receiving page.  The gui code is on the main page and the receiving page is located in a div within the main page but within no other div.

If I add a where to the select statement the fetch request doesn't seem to fire off at all. The echo 2 will display but the requested result wont.

```
  $r = $_POST["f2"];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE recipe ='".$r."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  echo "  2 ";

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "  " . $row['recipe'] ." ";
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your mysqli_connect() in the while loop, try moving the line `mysqli_close($con);` after the while loop in the second php script.

Comment: That did not work, I updated the current page that I am working with in the op code

Comment: Since I am not even getting an error back I am not sure whats going on with it